# Google Drive - Shared Drive: Identify if Sharable Link (AlternateLink) is enabled to be publicly shared

Tags: google-drive-api

Shared Drives with Google Drive API v2, I am trying to see if the file URL is shared or not.

In my shared drive, I am not able to differentiate if the file is shared(shareable link) or not. Is there a property if the sharable link is enabled, shared property is not available for Shared Drives. I see the alternateLink and webViewLink in both cases (WITH shareable link and WITH NO shareable link)

How can differentiate if the Sharable link enabled for public access through API

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check if a file is shared or not using [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk). You can use the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference#Permissions) resource to [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list) the active privileges of a file.

In this case, I understand that you want to know if a file is shared by a link or not. If that assumption is correct, you'll need to check the `withLink` property to see if the privilege requires the link or not.

With the permission resource you can check things like the `type` of user who has the privilege (single user, group, anyone…), the `role` (reader, writer, owner…) and many more information as listed in the linked documentation. Please, ask me if you still have any questions or need further clarifications.